# Spring Boot 2 Actuator Micrometer setup

Tags: spring, spring-boot, micrometer, spring-micrometer

I have a Spring Boot Application and I have this dependency:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.7.RELEASE</version> // From Parent
</dependency>
```

I have also configured my `application.yml` file to expose metrics:

```
management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: info, health, metrics
```

I have also created a Metrics bean for Kafka:

```
@Bean
public KafkaConsumerMetrics kafkaConsumerMetrics() {
  return new KafkaConsumerMetrics();
}
```

But when I hit the endpoint `GET http://localhost:8080/actuator/metrics` I get a `404 Page Not Found` error.

The other endpoints (info/health) works: http://localhost:8080/actuator/info and http://localhost:8080/actuator/health

What am I missing to get micrometer data?

Comment: Do you have spring security for `restricted` endpoints?

Comment: I don't think I do. How do I check or disable it?

Comment: Posted my answer. Let me know if it helped

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try enabling metrics from the configuration, though it should be enabled by default

```
management:
  endpoint:
    metrics:
      enabled: true
```

More details on actuator properties https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/appendix-application-properties.html#actuator-properties

Comment: Adding this to my yaml worked. The issue for me is that the tooltip for intellij told me it was defaulted to true. And so does the document you linked.